# How to stack overlapping list items

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 unordered lists that stack when in tablet and mobile view. Their `heights` are set to `0` until the `'column'` class is clicked, then they transition to a `max-height` using jQuery. This works fine until they stack. I have tried setting the **top li's** `position:relative;z-index:3`, **the middle li's** `position:relative;z-index:2;`, and **the bottom to li's** `position:relative;z-index:1`. However, they don't stack as expected. Is there something else that would not cause them to behave as expected? Thanks, any information would be helpful.

```
 <div class="container banner">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-4 column top-layer">
        <h3 class="text-center location-banner">Tampa</h3><span class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></span>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="banner-dropdown">
          <ul>
            <li class="top">Top</li>
            <li class="top">Top</li>
            <li class="top">Top</li>
            <li class="top">Top</li>
            <li class="top">Top</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 column middle-layer">
        <h3 class="text-center location-banner">Jacksonville</h3><span class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></span>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="banner-dropdown">
          <ul>
            <li class="middle">Middle</li>
            <li class="middle">Middle</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 column bottom-layer">
        <h3 class="text-center location-banner">Orlando</h3><span class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></span>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="banner-dropdown">
          <ul>
            <li class="bottom">Bottom</li>
            <li class="bottom">Bottom</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.banner-dropdown {
  max-height: 0;
  width: 102%;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgb(155, 155, 155);
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.top {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.middle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.bottom {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.column {
  background: rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.39);
  height: 48px;
  border: 4px solid #F8F8F8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS
When a column is clicked the corresponding ul height transitions to 205px. The problem is that is the view is > 991px and they stack they don't overlap each other properly. If the to ul is open and you open the middle ul it will show through the top div, and the middle ul goes beneath the bottom ul. Not sure if it has something to do with the height being added with jquery. If any more information is needed let me know. Thanks.

```
(function(){
  var cityDiv = $('.column');
  var span = $('span');

  cityDiv.click(function() {
    if ($(this).find('span').hasClass('fa-chevron-down')) {
      $(this).find('span').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
      $(this).find('.banner-dropdown').css('max-height','205px');
    } else {
      $(this).find('span').removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
      $(this).find('.banner-dropdown').css('max-height','0px');
    }
  });  
})
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant CSS? Also I'm not sure I completely understand the problem here. Can you create a fiddle to show us exactly what is not working as you'd expect?

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner, I added more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this ? 
[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxbLmLnq/2/)

I remove the `height` of `.column` :

```
.column {
  background: rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.39);
  border: 4px solid #F8F8F8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I also changed the `width` of `.banner-dropdown` to 100% instead of 102%.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made a fiddle to show the problem I'm having [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/railsarr/ce8tez9e/1/), I would like the ul's to overlap each other from top to bottom, however, the middle and bottom show through the top layer.

Comment: I just figured out the problem. I just needed to add the z-index to the columns themselves. Here is an updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/railsarr/ce8tez9e/2/), I was just over complicating it. Thanks for the effort!